# How can i check if i have a particular format

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Hello i want to know if there is a possible way to  check if a `String` has the particular format :

```
String : Double
```

This might sound silly cause you gonna tell me hey man you have already a string you can't do that.

What i am actually trying to do is have a function where it takes as a parameter one `String` and checks it, if under the hood A : `name (String) : Value(Double)` and after that i want to return the name as `String` and the value as `Double`. Is it possible and if yes how? thanks

edit : This is what exactly i want to do :

add a method to the `String Class`. The method takes a `String` of the format : `"work : 2380912831"`  and returns the given type and number, Where `type` should be `work` and `number` should be `2380912831`. If the argument that takes as parameter is not in the format `"type : number"` then the method should return nil

Comment: So a "valid" string would for example be "pi : 3.14"? There are many approaches, for example NSScanner or NSRegularExpression. You can split the string at ":" and examine both parts. .... Anything you tried so far?

Comment: the left part (the string) is one of the member of an Enum. I want to check if the string on the left side of ":" is inside of that enum. After that i want to check the right value and see if it is Double value. in case right of the ":" there is even one character i want my function to return nil. any ideas?

Comment: Please add all relevant information to the question itself. Nobody wants to browse all comments in order to understand your problem.

Comment: i just did that. Would you mind having a look at the description of my problem?:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @MartinR says, NSScanner is probably the best way to do this if you need flexibility and reusable code, but the quickest is `componentsSeparatedByString` - not so flexible, but dead easy:

```
func scan(inputString: String) -> (String, Double)? {
    let components = inputString.componentsSeparatedByString(":")
    if components.count == 2 {
        let s = components[0].stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())
        let d = (components[1] as NSString).doubleValue
        return (s, d)
    }
    return nil
}

print(scan("pi : 3.14")) // "Optional(("pi ", 3.14))\n"
print(scan("pi = 3.14")) // "nil\n"
print(scan("pi :")) // "Optional(("pi ", 0.0))\n"
print(scan("pi")) // "nil\n"
```

Watch out for how you want to treat spaces, nil double field after the colon, etc...

Comment: can you be a bit more specific about your last sentence : "Watch out for how you want to treat spaces, nil double field after the colon, etc..." cause i want after the semi colon to be one exactly " ". What should i implant in order to do that? Also isn't the upper code fail miserably in case i have two semi colons in the same code?

Comment: Any space after the colon will be ignored - but watch for a space before the colon as it will be appended to the string. If you might have another colon after the double, just change `== 2` to `>= 2` and it will ignore the second one...

Comment: Amended the code to remove trailing spaces if they exist. If you want to test for a nil double field after the colon, check whether `component[1]` is empty...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May i ask you another question? how can i check if that component[0] or s is a member of an enum? cause i have been trying for like 2 hours and can manage to get the answer

Comment: If your `enum` has a `String` raw value {e.g `enum TestEnum: String {...`) then yes, it's easy : `enum TestEnum: String {
    case Grimxn = "Grimxn"
    case Korpel = "Korpel"
    case Pi = "pi"
}

let x = scan("Korpel : 14")
if let s = x?.0, e = TestEnum(rawValue: s) {
    print(e.rawValue)
} else {
    print("\(x)'s string is not a valid TestEnum")
}`

Comment: and if it doesn't have a raw value? is it possible to have access?

Comment: Then I'm not sure what you mean - do you mean that the string matches the enum case's symbolic name? If that's what you mean then you'll have to extend the enum to return a string for each case, and test against that. Easier to have a raw value, if you have access to the original enum code...

Comment: I would suggest to use the `Double` initializer instead of converting the `String` to `NSString` and call `doubleValue`. So spaces get interpreted as `nil` instead of `0`.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but you need to strip the string of spaces (which you don't with `doubleValue`) since `Double(" 3.14")` gives `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use an [Extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html) for String class.
ex

```
extension String {
    var doubleValue:Double? {
        return NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(self)?.doubleValue
    }
}
```

and use it like:

```
"0.34".doubleValue       //0.34
"hello".doubleValue      // nil
```

Comment: That won't work cause i wont it to check if left of ":" we have a string and right of ":" we have a double.

Comment: also please have a look at the description i edited my post in order to make more clear what i need:)

Comment: Ok, now I understood. You need to add a function to that extension taking your string as a parameter and returning an optional tuple. In that function split your parameter string with `.componentsSeparatedByString(":")`  and check if second of splitted values is a double, then return your tuple `(String, Double)`

Answer (score 0):

just separate your string by ":"

ex.

var myString = "A:123"

var myArray = myString.componentsSeparatedByString(":")

//Returns an array with the following values: ["A", "123"]